# Absolute path in Python requiring an extra leading forward slash?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, path

I am trying to open a resource via an absolute path on my Macbook with `open(file[,mode])`. The resource I am trying to access is not in the same folder as the script that is running. If I use something like `/Users/myname/Dev/project/resource` I get an `IOError: No such file or directory`. Whats confusing me is that if i add and extra forward slash to the beginning so it starts with `//Users/...` it finds the resource without a problem.

What is going on here?

Comment: Show exactly how you're using it and the actual error with the path shown.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with this is to avoid constructing the path yourself altogether. Let os.path.join() do it for you.